# Counting array reference input and displaying count -- infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am trying to display the occurrence of how many times an integer occurs in an array but I get an infinite loop/logic error. For instance, if the user enters: 2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 23, 43, 2, 0 then it should display:

```
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 1 time
4 occurs 1 time
5 occurs 2 times
6 occurs 1 time
23 occurs 1 time
43 occurs 1 time
```

Any help would really be appreciated. *Note: This is not an assignment or homework, It is a exercise question from intro to Java book by Y.D. Lang*

```
import java.util.*;

public class CountNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");
        int[] arrayRefVar = createList();
        int[] countNum = countNumbers(arrayRefVar);
        displayCount(countNum, arrayRefVar);
    }

    public static int[] createList() {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] List = new int[100];
        int i = 0;

        while (List[i] != 0) {
            List[i] = Input.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        return List;
    }

    public static int[] countNumbers(int[] List) {
        int[] count = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            count[i] = i;
        }

        int[] countNum = new int[List.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < countNum.length; i++) {
            countNum[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < count.length; j++) {
                if (List[i] == count[j]) {
                    countNum[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return countNum;
    }

    public static void displayCount(int[] countList, int[] arrayRefVar) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayRefVar.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayRefVar[i] + " occurs " + countList[i] + " " + checkPlural(arrayRefVar[i]));
        }
    }

    public static String checkPlural(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            return "times";
        } else {
            return "time";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to import java.util.*, you might avoid using `List` as a variable.  It's not going to work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input should end in `0`, then you should check whether the currently read int is zero or not.

```
while(i < List.length) {
    List[i] = Input.nextInt();
    if(List[i] == 0)
        break ;
    ++i;
}
```

Since you are checking for the condition after incrementing `i`, you are not checking the current value.

Note : `nextInt()` method from the `Scanner` class can throw exceptions namely : `InputMismatchException`, `NoSuchElementException` and `IllegalStateException`. So either handle it in a try catch block or make the caller handle it by throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got it after countless tries, if anybody has any suggestions to make the code more efficient the input would be greatly appreciated. Here it is:

import java.util.Random;

public class CountSingleDigits {

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int[] arrayRefVar = createList();

    int[] counts = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        counts[i] = i;
    }

    int[] tempCounts = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayRefVar.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

            if (arrayRefVar[i] == counts[j]) {

                tempCounts[j]++;    
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        System.out.println(counts[i] + " appears " + tempCounts[i] + " times ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayRefVar.length; i++) {

        if (i % 10 == 0) {

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.print(arrayRefVar[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static int[] createList() {

    Random f = new Random();

    int[] List = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {

        List[i] = f.nextInt(9);
    }

    return List;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

One issue is that your while loop for user input is never entered. You use 0 as the sentinel value to exit user input, however, when you initialize an array of integers, they are all 0 by default.

```
int[] List = new int[100];

int i = 0;
//problem: while loop never entered
while (List[i] != 0) {
```

Comment: Not true, look at the following line. He is changing the array content.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking Can you be more specific please? The code that I quoted from him will never ask for user input. He initialized an array of integers, and then immediately checks the condition (List[0] != 0). It will never be true, unless he asks for input first, before looping...